# C# Unable to convert .csv columns to list of lists for JSON conversion

Tags: c#, json, csv

I am making a post request to an API which consumes the below format (a list of lists).

```
var data = "{\"Coord\" : [[50.452603, 30.522025],[30.621929, 31.012975]]}";
```

I have a .csv file that has a lat and lng column which I would like to convert to the above JSON format.

| Lat | Lng |
| --- | --- |
| 50.452603 | 30.522025 |
| 30.621929 | 31.012975 |

Below is an example of my code, but its a list of dictionaries. I'm not sure how to adapt this to create the above.

```
WorkBook workbook = WorkBook.LoadCSV("C:\\local\\Test\\Test.csv", fileFormat: ExcelFileFormat.XLSX, listDelimiter: ",");
WorkSheet ws = workbook.DefaultWorkSheet;
DataTable dt = ws.ToDataTable(true);

List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Comment: Share a few rows from the csv file. Also, running through Excel is among the least-effective, most error-prone, and slowest possible solutions for reading CSV.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank you. I have added a table into the question body. Can you suggest a better method for reading the .csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That json is also compatible with a List of arrays, which I think makes more sense here. There are some other improvements we can make as well. Start with this, which uses the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace (there are even better csv parsers on NuGet, but this is built-in):

```
IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCSV(string path)
{
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

        parser.ReadFields(); // read past the header
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            yield return parser.ReadFields();
        }
    }
}
```

And then have a class like this:

```
class JsonCoordHelper {
    public IEnumerable<string[]> Coord {get;set;}
}
```

We can use them like this:

```
var data = new JsonCoordHelper();
data.Coord = ReadCSV(@"C:\local\Test\Test.csv");
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/KAdjFK

Note I used `string[]` instead of `double[]` or similar, because the values end up as strings again in the json file anyway. However, this does leave some extra quote marks. If you need to do further processing of the data in your own program, or if those quote marks turn out to be significant, you may want to parse the values as `double`:

```
class JsonCoordHelper {
    public IEnumerable<double[]> Coord {get;set;}
}

// ...
data.Coord = ReadCSV(@"C:\local\Test\Test.csv").
                Select(r => r.Select(c => double.Parse(c)).ToArray() );
```

But don't do the above unless you need to, as it's a lot of extra array allocations and thanks to internationalization/cultural issues parsing numbers from strings isn't the efficient or simple operation we think it should be.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I do have a header column. I'm not really sure exactly how that code is working. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I'm having some issues finding the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace. I'm using .NET Framework 4.8. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: That namespace is definitely there, going all the way back to .Net 1.0. You don't even need to add a reference.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is saying the type or namespace name 'TextFieldParser' could not be found. Let me double check my references.

Comment: Hmm... looks like this may have changed as part of the prep for .Net Core, where they couldn't inlcude the Microsoft-only stuff out of the box anymore, and you may need to add the VisualBasic.dll reference manually. But it IS still included with the 4.8 installer (the dll will be on the machine as part of the framework).

Comment: Yes I have added the reference and it is picking it up now thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, probably the best answer I have had. I've run that json through the API and it works. Quick question out of interest you were saying if it does need to be data type double use ReadCSV... how does that work? Thanks.

Comment: That's the snippet at the bottom.

Comment: Also made a couple other changes to remove the need for spurious and wasteful `ToList()` calls.